# want to build wxPython on cygwin --with-msw

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Hello wxWidgets and wxPython people,  I want to build wxWidgets and wxPython on cygwin, but use windows widgets ( --with-msw ) so as to not require X.   This seems possible and appears to be done previously by others, but perhaps not for some time.  I have successfully build wxWidgets, but the build scripts
for wxPython do not seem to support this out-of-the box.  I have hacked on this with 2.8 and 3.0.2 verions.  Phoenix versions would be fine, too if that would be better.  thx. tnordland7

Comment: are you saying you already fixed the build? Or you are asking if someone did?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build under Cygwin is by using MinGW-w64 cross-compiler. If you do this, i.e. specify `--host=i686-w64-mingw32` or `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` to configure, wxMSW should already be selected automatically and you shouldn't have much to do.

If you really want to create a Cygwin, as opposed to native, application (but why?), you may need to use `--with-msw` explicitly because Cygwin is considered to be a Unix environment and there may indeed be problems because, to be frank, this is a build variant that nobody uses any more. If you're interested in making it work, please check 3.1.5 and/or latest Git and let us know, or ideally fix, about any problems you encounter.

But if you just want to make things work in the Cygwin environment, using MinGW cross-compiler (available in Cygwin) is by far the simplest and IMO better option.

Comment: I wish I could say that I fixed the build on wxWidgets... I configured wxWidgets with --with-msw, then hacked the Makefiles (which indicates the build is not supportive), and hacked fixes into the source as well... not production code.   I was able to gen the widgets and run forty against them.   The reason I am trying to do this is that I need the posix goodness but want to avoid X, mingw etc will produce a windows native app, and I would lose the posix stuff.   Is there a downrev wxWidgets codebase in which this was still supported? thx

Comment: No, sorry, I can't say. You should at least report the problems you've encountered to wxTrac (unless they're already reported there, which is not impossible).